# SQNR for quantizer

Tags: signal-analysis

For this type of input (top) and output (bottom) [image: noise] which of these equations is required for the SQNR: [image: 1] or [image: 2]

Comment: Not really a duplicate since the answers are different although the user could have asked both questions in one of the "questions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 1.76 dB is assuming the "S" is a sine wave with amplitude right up to the rails (which has "sinusoidal distribution") and "QN" is the quantization error (which has uniform distribution).  if you assume both S and QN have uniform distribution (which is what you might have with a triangle waveform cranked up to the rails), then the 1.76 dB goes away.

Comment: in what sense triangle?

Comment: as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave or even a sawtooth wave http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave .  both have uniform PDF.  if you have one of those, with amplitude to the maximum possible level, you get 6.02 dB of signal to noise ratio for every bit in the resulting quantized word.